# Help needed for setting key-val options for my package

Tags: key-value, pgfopts

I want to use key-svalue options for my package and I tried a solution with
pgfopts. It must be possible 1) to load the package with e.g.

```
\usepackage[colors=1]{mypack}
```

2) to change the color somewhere in the usercode, not only in the
preamble, with something like

```
\MPset{colors=2}
```

and 3) to test which color is active.

In my real world package there are 2 more options concerning language and
messages, so maybe pgfopts is an overkill. I would gladly accept any working
solution with any key-val package.

```
\ProvidesPackage{mypack}
\RequirePackage{%
xcolor,
pgfopts
}

\def\MPset#1{\pgfqkeys{/MP}{ /#1}}
\MPset{colors/.initial=2}
\MPset{colors/.is choice}
\MPset{colors/1/.code={\def\test{\textcolor{black}{TEST}}}}
\MPset{colors/2/.code={\def\test{\textcolor{red}{TEST}}}}
\MPset{colors/3/.code={\def\test{\textcolor{blue}{TEST}}}}

\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/MP}
\endinput% mypack.sty
```

I use mypack in this test document

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[colors=1]{mypack}
\usepackage{mypack}
\MPset{colors=2}
\begin{document}
  :\pgfkeysvalueof{colors}:
  \test
\end{document}
\endinput
```

If I load mypack with

```
\usepackage[colors=1]{mypack}
```

I get this error

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/MP/colors', to which you
  passed '1', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.16 \ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/MP}
```

If I load mypack without an option it does compile, but

```
\pgfkeysvalueof{colors}
```

is empty. When I uncomment

```
\test
```

I get the wanted colored text, but I still cannot test which color is active

Comment: Your `\MPset` macro should be defined by `def\MPset#1{\pgfqkeys{/MP}{#1}}`

Comment: Your test should be `\pgfkeysvalueof{/MP/colors}`.

Comment: @Paul I thought I tried all possible combinations. Must have overlooked some! With eihter option or through MPset, I get the right color now. But the test always yields 2, the initial value. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a corrected version of your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%------------------------------
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mypack.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{mypack}
\RequirePackage{%
xcolor,
pgfopts
}

\pgfkeys{/MP/.is family}
\def\MPset#1{\pgfkeys{/MP,#1}}
\MPset{
  colors/.is choice,
  colors/1/.code={\def\test{\textcolor{black}{TEST}}},
  colors/2/.code={\def\test{\textcolor{red}{TEST}}},
  colors/3/.code={\def\test{\textcolor{blue}{TEST}}},
  % default value
  colors=2,
}

\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/MP}
\endinput% mypack.sty
\end{filecontents*}
%------------------------------

\usepackage[colors=3]{mypack}
%\MPset{colors=2}
\begin{document}
  \test
\end{document}
```

Here is a modified version to (*try to*) match your requirements.

- The `\MPspecial` macro uses the `MP@uses@italic` TeX-if to choose between italic or color.
- The `use italic` key sets the `MP@uses@italic` TeX-if to true or false.
- The `define current color` key defines the current color (via xcolor) and incidentally store its current name in `\MP@current@color`.
- The `colors` key is a choice with three alternatives (black, blue, red) and defines the `MP current color`. The red and blue colors set `use italic` to false and the black color sets `use italic` to true.

```
\documentclass{article}
%------------------------------
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mypack.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{mypack}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}

\newif\ifMP@uses@italic
\pgfkeys{/MP/.is family}
\def\MPset#1{\pgfkeys{/MP,#1}}
\MPset{
  % some special macros use italic istead of black
  use italic/.is if=MP@uses@italic,
  use italic=false, % default value
  % define the current color
  define current color/.code={\def\MPcurrent@color@name{#1}\colorlet{current MP color}{#1}},
  % 
  colors/.is choice,
  colors/black/.style={use italic=true,define current color=black},
  colors/red/.style={use italic=false,define current color=red},
  colors/blue/.style={use italic=false,define current color=blue},
  % default value
  colors=red,
}

\def\MPspecial#1{\ifMP@uses@italic\textit{#1}\else\textcolor{current MP color}{#1}\fi}
\def\test{\textcolor{current MP color}{TEST (in \MPcurrent@color@name)}}

\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/MP}
\endinput% mypack.sty
\end{filecontents*}
%------------------------------
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[colors=red]{mypack}
\begin{document}
\test{} \MPspecial{My text}

\MPset{colors=black}
\test{} \MPspecial{My text}

\MPset{colors=blue}
\test{} \MPspecial{My text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Paul. Unfortunately, the test  \pgfkeysvalueof{/MP/colors} still yields the empty string.

Comment: @Jack It's normal. The `.is choice` handler defines the `/MP/colors` key as a command (like a macro), not as a value.

Comment: Dear Paul, thanks again for your answer. As a complete novice with regard to pgfopts, I have a couple of questions: 1) My requirement nr 3 stated that it must be possible to test which color is active. Of course I can do that by storing this information in the code for the colors. Is it impossible retrieve this directly from pgfopts? 2) Why did you introduce "family"? 3) Is the "choice" related to the fact that it is an option of the package or just that the user can select a value at any time? 4) Do you think pgfopts is the right approach for this simple application? Regards  Jack

Comment: 1) Why do you want to "test which color is active"? It's probably an XY problem! What is your real need? 2) `family` is only a writing facility. 3) `.is choice` allows to define the authorized values. 4) Any key/value package could be suitable. `pgfopts`(in fact `pgfkeys`) is just the most powerful.

Comment: 1) I set diagrams and to mark a special situation, some things are written in red. When the user specifies only 1 color (=black and white), I use italics to mark this situation. (Sorry, I don't know what an XY problem is). 2) So one can leave it out without changing something else?  4) I know that, but do I need this power for this tiny application? BTW does not answering my question 1, implies that pgfopts cannot do that directly?
Regards

Comment: @Jack [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thanks for your patience and clarifying it. Yes, this is clearly a 
XY problem. I got trapped by the additional color requirement and after that the italics one in the final stage of the project.

Comment: I am really impressed of what is  possible with pgfopts. In the meantime I use the previous solution and then flag the colors=1 case, which I can test in the appropriate places.
I have to think about which solution will be implemented in the end, but either way, you solved my problem. Thanks